# Twilio verification response on nodejs backend service contains all my environment variables, how to safeguard them?

Tags: node.js, security, environment-variables, twilio, twilio-verify

I've been looking through my in-production app's logs in GCP and noticed that the verification response that I am logging contains all my process.env values and secrets including TLS certificates, DB connection strings, everything.

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Which makes me realise this is probably something that any third party dependency with outbound connections can do.

My questions are:

- is this normal
- how can I check if the values are actually sent to a remote server
- how can I prevent it -- if at all

Comment: This seems to be the response of the server application (and not from Twilio's verify service). Can you share the code that is executed when this endpoint is requested?

Comment: HI @IObert -- this is the whole response from this call: 

await this.twilio.verify.v2
        .services(this.secrets.get('TWILIO_VERIFY_SID'))
        .verificationChecks.create({
          to,
          code,
        });

where twilio is:     this.twilio = new tw.Twilio(sid, token);

Comment: It seems to be your code is returning the full client object. When I check the response of the verificationChecks.create() call, it only have the following props:
`['_version', 'sid', 'serviceSid', 'accountSid', 'to', 'channel', 'status', 'valid', 'amount', 'payee', 'dateCreated', 'dateUpdated', 'snaAttemptsErrorCodes', '_context', '_solution']`. Which client version are you using?